# How to setup TailwindCSS in Angular 11.2.0 or lower

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

As you know Tailwind is a very popular PostCSS solution. I want to add TailwindCSS in my Angular app running version 11.2.0 or with older versions. How can I do so?

**I decided to post and answer my own question because this is a very popular question I have seen through the Angular community recently**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Setup TailwindCSS in Angular 11.2.0

1. Install with `npm install -D tailwindcss`
2. Install TailwindCSS plugins(Optional):

- `npm i @tailwindcss/typography`
- `npm i @tailwindcss/forms`

3. Create a TailwindCSS configuration file in the workspace or project root. Name that configuration file `tailwind.config.js`

It should look like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    prefix: '',
    purge: {
      content: [
        './src/**/*.{html,ts}',
      ]
    },
    darkMode: 'class', // or 'media' or 'class'
    theme: {
      extend: {},
    },
    variants: {
      extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms'),require('@tailwindcss/typography')],
};
```

4. In your styles.scss file add the following TailwindCSS imports

```css
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

if you are using CSS not SCSS, your file should look like this:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

### Making sure TailwindCSS in Angular is working

Go to any of you components and write the following:

```html
<button
  class="py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-red-400">Hello</button>
```

Now run `ng serve`, you should see the following button

[image: angular tailwindcss]

### How to purge TailwindCSS in Production

If we don't purge, our CSS can be very heavy due to all the CSS classes TailwindCSS adds for you. If you purge, all the unused classes will be removed.

The way I figured to do purging in Angular 11.2.0 are the following ways:

A)  This is my preferred way. Add this to your building SCRIPT `NODE_ENV=production ng build --prod`
and your tailwind.config.js file should look like this.

```js
purge: {
      enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      content: [
        './src/**/*.{html,ts}',
      ]
    },
```

B) In your `tailwind.config.js file` you can set the `enabled` property inside of the `purge` property to `true`. This will run purge all the time, be aware of that.

```js
....
prefix: '',
    purge: {
      enabled: true,
      content: [
        './src/**/*.{html,ts}',
      ]
    },
....
```

Then you can run `ng build --prod` and you will see your bundle since getting smaller.

**Before purging**

[image: tailwindcss purging]

**After purging**

[image: purging tailwind]

To learn more about Angular (11.2.0 or older version) with TailwindCSS, look at my article

https://dev.to/angular/setup-tailwindcss-in-angular-the-easy-way-1i5l